# Combining loop with until in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to check whether is this the proper way to use loop with until. What i need to do is for each loop, a condition need to be achieved. If the condition achieved loop another time

Below is my code

```
- shell: "{{ item.script_location }}/{{ item.script_name }}"
  loop: "{{ script_list }}"
  loop_control:
    pause: 10
  when:  item.isExecuteScript | bool == true and inventory_hostname in groups['all'][5:]
  register: verify_status
  until: verify_status.stdout == "executed"
  retries: 1030  delay: 5
```

vars.yml

```
script_list
  - { isExecuteScript: "true", script_name: "varify_stat_application.sh", script_location: "/home/application" }
  - { isExecuteScript: "true", script_name: "varify_stat_server.sh", script_location: "/home/server" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Q: **"*Is this the proper way to use `loop` with `until`?*"**

A: No. It is not. [until](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) doesn't work with `loop`. It is not possible to break a loop. A `loop` is running until it completes all items and `until` makes a task repeatedly running until a condition is met. Use `when` if you want to conditionally omit items in a loop.

Comment: hi if this the case, what will be the best approach as i need to use loop to loop the items in the list of vars.  but same time each loop need success first before moving to second loop. if u have any hint please share

Comment: Make it [mre] and remove what' not relevant(isExecuteScript, inventory_hostname, ...).

Comment: hi, i will make the changes. i test my code out and it was working. why is it like that. as u stated by right loop cant work with until. but i test it out it was working. any idea pls share